# gridview layout center(android)

Tags: android, xml, gridview

Sorry for my english. I want locate `gridview` in center layout. But i have this:

[image].

I use this properties `android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"` and `android:gravity="center"` but its not help

```
<LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
   <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <service.ExpandableHeightGridView
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:id="@+id/gridView"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="1dp"
                        android:columnWidth="150dp"
                        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
                        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
                        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
                        android:verticalSpacing="1dp"
                        android:focusable="true"
                        android:clickable="true"/>

                </RelativeLayout>
 </LinearLayout>
```

**ExpandableHeightGridView**

```
public class ExpandableHeightGridView extends GridView
{

    boolean expanded = false;

    public ExpandableHeightGridView(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
    }

    public ExpandableHeightGridView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public ExpandableHeightGridView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
                                    int defStyle)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public boolean isExpanded()
    {
        return expanded;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
    {
        // HACK! TAKE THAT ANDROID!
        if (isExpanded())
        {
            // Calculate entire height by providing a very large height hint.
            // View.MEASURED_SIZE_MASK represents the largest height possible.
            int expandSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(MEASURED_SIZE_MASK,
                    MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, expandSpec);

            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = getLayoutParams();
            params.height = getMeasuredHeight();
        }
        else
        {
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        }
    }

    public void setExpanded(boolean expanded)
    {
        this.expanded = expanded;
    }
}
```

Item `gridview`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="1dp"
    android:paddingLeft="1dp"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageRoom"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:id="@+id/textView30"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can you post whole xml layout in which gridview is present ?

Comment: @NileshJarad thanks for answer. i update my question, its item gridview

Comment: you need to post `ExpandableHeightGridView` parent

Comment: @NileshJarad aa.. sorry, i update

Comment: I need upper part and below part of that see your question

Comment: Add `android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"` to the parent layout of your `ExpandableHeightGridView` in the xml file.

Comment: @Rami i add this. In my questions i write this, its not work for me

Comment: In your question you added them to *ExpandableHeightGridView* not to his parent.

Comment: @Rami aaa... i update my question